# Do while loop for catching exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, do-while

Java beginner here. Im trying to create a do while loop where the user is supposed to key in some info. If the user keys in the correct info for `something_A`, the program should move on to asking user to key in info for `something_B`.

If the user enters incorrect info for this, the program should throw the respective exception which is `InvalidExcep_B`. I can get all this to work except once the exception is thrown, the program prompts the user to key in info from the beginning.

What should I do in order for the program to keep prompting only to input the piece of info that was incorrect?

```
boolean continueInput = true;
    
    userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(); 
    
    do {
        try {  
                         
            System.out.print("Enter Something_A: ");
            something_A = userInput.nextInt();

            
            if (condition ok) {
                run statements;
            }

            
            System.out.print("Enter Something_B: ");
            something_B = userInput.nextInt();


            if (condition ok) {
                run statements;
            }
            
            System.out.print("Enter Something_C: ");
            something_C = userInput.nextInt();


            if (condition ok) {
                run statements;
            }
            
            continueInput = false;
        }
        
        catch (InvalidExcep_A e) {
            
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            continueInput = true;
        }
        
        catch (InvalidExcep_B e) {
            
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            continueInput = true;
        }
        
        catch (InvalidExcep_C e) {
            
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            continueInput = true;
        }
        
    } while (continueInput == true);
          
    
    
    System.out.print("Enter Something_D: ");
    something_D = userInput.next();

    printInfo (parameters);
}
```

This is what I have so far. Thank you!

Comment: `run` is not a keyword in Java.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you could try.

- Separating the do-while per input (right now, you have it all in one do-while). A bit repetitive but hey, it gets the job done.
- Store a list of [input, actions] and just iterate through that in your while loop, the stop condition being once you finish that list.

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost correct except since we need to remember whether `Something_A` is already finished or not. Similarly, for `Something_B` and `Something_C` we have to remember whether it is finished or not. So, the condition for `Something_A`, `Something_B` and `Something_C` should be different. Hence I chose `conditionA`, `conditionB` and `conditionC` for `Something_A`, `Something_B` and `Something_C` respectively.

---

The following code should solve your problem:

```
boolean continueInput = true;
boolean conditionA = true, conditionB = true, conditionC = true;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println(); 

int somethingA = -1, somethingB = -1, somethingC = -1;
String somethingD = "";

do {
    try {  
        if (conditionA) {
            System.out.print("Enter Something_A: ");
            somethingA = userInput.nextInt();
//            runStatementsA();
            conditionA = false; // Will not prompt for Something_A again.
        }
        
        if (conditionB) {
            System.out.print("Enter Something_B: ");
            somethingB = userInput.nextInt();
//            runStatementsB();
            conditionB = false; // Will not prompt for Something_B again.
        }
        
        if (conditionC) {
            System.out.print("Enter Something_C: ");
            somethingC = userInput.nextInt();
//            runStatementsX();
            conditionC = false; // Will not prompt for SOmething_C again.
        }
        
        continueInput = false;
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException  e) { // Replace 'java.util.InputMismatchException' with 'InvalidExcep_A'
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        userInput.next(); // Flush the scanner object
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) { // Replace 'java.lang.NullPointerException' with 'InvalidExcep_B'
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        userInput.next(); // Flush the scanner object
    } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) { // Replace 'java.lang.RuntimeException' with 'InvalidExcep_C'
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        userInput.next(); // Flush the scanner object
    }
    
} while (continueInput == true);

System.out.print("Enter Something_D: ");
somethingD = userInput.next();

//printInfo(parameters);
```